# TypeORM Entity relation with itself

Tags: javascript, typescript, entity, relationship, typeorm

I have a entity called "Comments", the idea is having replies for these comments. I can have also replies for replies. Example as following:

```
-Comment1
---Reply 1 Of Comment 1
-----Reply Of Reply 1
---Reply 2 Of Comment 1
-----Reply1 Of Reply 2
-------Reply1 Of Reply 1 of Reply 2
-Comment2
```

The entity is this one:

```
@Entity('comments') {
    @PrimaryGenerated()
    id: string;

    @Column()
    message: string;

    @Column()
    date: Date;
}
```

The approach I was thinking of is to have a "self relationship" where I could create another field maybe called "parent_id" and where I have this field filled, I consider as a reply.
Any ideas of how I can do this "self relationship" or ideas of another approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [self referencing](https://typeorm.io/#/relations-faq/how-to-create-self-referencing-relation) relation:

```
@Entity('comments')
export class Comment {
    @PrimaryGenerated()
    id: string;

    @Column()
    message: string;

    @Column()
    date: Date;

    @Column()
    parentId: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => Comment, comment => comment.children)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "parentId" })
    parent: Comment;

    @OneToMany(type => Category, comment => comment.parent)
    children: Comment[];
}
```

Also you can look at [Tree Entities](https://typeorm.io/#/tree-entities) as another approach.